# Printing after a network change causes applications to hang

Tags: networking, printing

My problem is as follows:

I have a laptop with Ubuntu (based on a bare-bones server 19.10 install, so no Gnome or other frameworks) that I use in multiple places and on different networks.  The different printer configurations are handled by having `~/.cups/client.conf` being a symbolic link to a network-specific configuration that specifies the cups server to use.

Although it is cumbersome to modify the link each time I switch networks (is there a better way, btw?), it works.  Except that applications apparently cache printer information, and for applications kept running across a network change, when I try to print they will hang for ages waiting for a cups server that no longer is available.  Affected programs are Chrome and Libreoffice, but not, I think, Firefox.

Is there a way to reset the printer configuration for these applications?

Comment: What do you mean by bare-bones installation of Ubuntu?  Ubuntu desktop comes with GNOME by default if it's a modern installation, so are you talking about a server? or older release?  Please be specific, as we don't know your release or if you're talking about server (which explains the no-gnome, but not chrome or libreoffice) or desktop, nor what release.

Comment: Using the server install, and adding applications and components I need.  Will clarify in the text as well.

Comment: I still don't see your release details.

Comment: Sorry.  Ubuntu 19.10